# find the first word of the first element of a list of tuples in a column?

Tags: python, dataframe, tuples

I have a datafreme like this:

```
import pandas as pd

test = {'text': [
    ('tom-mark', 'tom', 'tom is a good guy.'),
    ('Nick X','nick', 'Is that Nick?')
]}, {'text': [
    ('juli', 'juli', 'Tom likes juli so much.'),
    ('tony', 'tony', 'Steve and Tony listen in as well.')
]}
```

I want to find the first word in the first element of each tuple (i.e. tom, Nick, juli, tony).

I tried the following code but it can't deal with '-' in tom-mark'

```
    name = t[0].lower()
    name = name.split()
    name = name[0]
```

However, some tuples have 2 words as the first element. How could I find the first word of each tuple?

Comment: This is not using pandas at all.  Is that OK?

Comment: This might be a good case for regular expressions.  `\w` will match alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas dataframe and use a function to map the values of the `text` column to get the first name and then create a list out of list of lists for that specific column.

Inside the function, use regular expression to extract only the first name from all tuples in that list and return a list of first names.

```
import pandas as pd
import re


def get_first(x):
    return list(map(lambda tup: re.match(r'\w+', tup[0])[0].lower(), x))

test = {'text': [
    ('tom-mark', 'tom', 'tom is a good guy.'),
    ('Nick X','nick', 'Is that Nick?')
]}, {'text': [
    ('juli', 'juli', 'Tom likes juli so much.'),
    ('tony', 'tony', 'Steve and Tony listen in as well.')
]}

data = sum(pd.DataFrame(test).applymap(get_first)['text'].tolist(), [])

print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question, how could replace the '-' with ' ' (i.e. space) in the original data (i.e. test)

Comment: For that you can use `return list(map(lambda tup: re.match(r'\w+', tup[0].replace('-', ''))[0].lower(), x))` inside the function `get_first` instead of the `return list(map(lambda tup: re.match(r'\w+', tup[0])[0].lower(), x))`.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this help:

```py
import re

test = {'text': [
    ('tom-mark', 'tom', 'tom is a good guy.'),
    ('Nick X','nick', 'Is that Nick?'),
    ('juli', 'juli', 'Tom likes juli so much.'),
    ('tony', 'tony', 'Steve and Tony listen in as well.')]
}

first_names = []

for names in test['text']:
    name = re.match(r'\w+', names[0])
    first_names.append(name[0].lower())


print(first_names)

['tom', 'nick', 'juli', 'tony']
```